# jquery validate add method to validate datetime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, datepicker

I'm using a datetimepicker plugin that I found [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) which works quite well.

The only problem now is that it breaks the standard date validation included with the [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) because of the added time on the end of the string in the input box.

Here is what I have so far in a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XH4sh/4/). I added a validation method that checks if the value is a date, but it doesn't accept the time.

I need help with writing the custom validation method. How do I split the `date` and `time` string and then perform the tests to validate them?

Thanks

Comment: There is no functioning date-picker in your jsFiddle.

Comment: @Sparky I get a Forbidden when I try to browse to the DateTimePicker addon site. Is there a way to upload the library instead of pointing to it? I'm guessing not.

Comment: You have to find a CDN link, otherwise, you can paste the content of the plugin into the JavaScript pane.

Comment: Not really sure what you want from us here.  No, there are no rules that already validate date & time as part of this plugin.  Yes, you will need to write a custom method as you've already guessed.  Yes, I'd split it, validate the date portion as it's already done, then validate the time separately, while keeping both parts within the same method.  Are you looking for help with writing a custom method?  If so, please fix your question as such.

Comment: I edited the question, I'll spend a bit more time with my wording next time. I've made this same error on previous questions and I can see how it's confusing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You already have validation for the `date` rule.  Otherwise, you can look inside the jQuery Validate plugin to obtain that:

```
date: function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
},
```

Here is a custom method I found for validating the `time` portion of your string.

```
$.validator.addMethod("time", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid time.");
```

**Time Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/9CdvN/**

Simply combine the two functions into your "DateTime" method.  Then split your input value at the space and test each part accordingly.

---

Here's a demo where I've combined the Date & Time methods together.  It accepts the following format, `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm`, so you'll simply need to tweak it a bit.

**http://jsfiddle.net/9CdvN/2/**

Answer (score 1):

The datetime picker you mentioned says it uses jQuery UI's datepicker widget. You can control the format of the date you receive from the widget using the ui datepicker API, specifically the [dateFormat method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

You should be able to set the datepicker up to supply a date in the format that you need for your validation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Setting the date and time formats does not validate properly. I really think I'm going to need a custom validation method to handle the compound Date and Time string.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you switch plugins? http://www.datejs.com/ has an outstanding number of ways to validate dates and some ridiculous syntactic sugar:

```
// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

Comment: I'll take a look at that plugin and see if it fits my needs. Thanks

Comment: @Wartickler- the library is still in Alpha status. It looks good but I would like something more mature. Thanks

Comment: It's Javascript! (albeit, jQuery-style) How much more mature do you need!  (O;

Comment: I hear ya, but I still don't want to chase down bugs only to find out it was an Alpha library causing my woes. I'll keep my eye on it for beta or stable status :)