# How to validate <input type="time"> within timeframe with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form with `<input type="time">` were I want it to validate based on a specific timeframe, e.g. it should only validate between 08:00 and 22:00.

I have tried using the min / max values, but that doesn't work for validation...

```
<input type="time" min="0800" max="2200" required>
```

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Any tips on how I can accomplish this and if its even possible?

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/LJz5x/) to see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you even try or do you have an attempt to show us?

Comment: I'll post my code shortly...

Comment: Regardless of how you accomplish this on the client, you'll still need server-side validation...

Comment: @MarcB Isn't jQuery Validation Plugin adequate?

Comment: @Prodac: What if I disable Javascript in my Client? Or what if I try to run a command in a firebug console editing the values before submit? You can't be sure, the value sent to the server is valid.

Comment: @Seika85 As this is for an app that will be running on Facebook only, I'm not concerned on that at this time. But thanks for the heads up =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom validator, something like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("timey", function(value, element) {
    var hour = parseInt(value.substring(0,2));
    return hour > 7 && hour < 23;
}, "Invalid time");
```

Then apply that to your field. Be careful about field names, though- it looks like the JSFiddle you posted isn't set up properly.

Setting up the min and max properly (`min="08:00:00" max="22:00:00"`) is more elegant, but the validator doesn't seem to handle the edge cases properly, rejecting exactly 8:00 and 22:00.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LJz5x/2/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all as stated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html) the min/max attributes should be formatted as datetime values like `min="08:00:00"` and `max="22:00:00"`.

---

For jQuery validation, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787503/jquery-validate-add-method-to-validate-datetime):

```
date: function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
},
```

and for time validation within the given input string:

```
$.validator.addMethod("time", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid time.");
```